# Invoke different contract in a single Chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-chaincode

I am using hyperledger-fabric 1.4 for developing a simple chaincode that saves the project information.
I am working on a existing code repository that contains chain code function calls using, facing many difficulties already in running the network. I managed to get the chaincode installed on 2 peers.
Now i am on invoking the chain code part. I know that in fabric-client two types there are bootstrap identities and then enrollment strategies for users and admins.

What I am trying to achieve is to write separate contract files say Project and Folder, install these contract files as single chaincode and then invoke these contract functions using client.

Originally the repository contain only one contract that was built using shim:

```
const util = require('util');

var Chaincode = class {
    async Init(stub) {
        return shim.success();
    }

    async Invoke(stub) {
        let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
        console.info(ret);
        let method = this[ret.fcn];
        if (!method) {
            return shim.success();
        }
        try {
            let payload = await method(stub, ret.params, this);
            return shim.success(payload);
        } catch (err) {
            return shim.error(err);
        }
    }

    async save(stub, args, thisClass) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({result: 400, message: "Invalid arguments"}));
        }

        let transactionHash = stub.getTxID();
        let timeStamp = stub
            .getTxTimestamp()
            .seconds
            .low;

        try {
            let order = JSON.parse(args[0]);
            order.updateLogs = [
                {
                    transactionHash: transactionHash,
                    createdAt: timeStamp,
                    completedMilestone: order.completedMilestone
                }
            ]
            let orderAsByte = await stub.getState(order.orderId);
            if (orderAsByte && orderAsByte.length > 0) {
                return Buffer.from(
                    JSON.stringify({result: 409, message: "order already exist"})
                );
            }
            await stub.putState(order.orderId, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(order)));
            return Buffer.from(
                JSON.stringify({result: 200, message: 'successfully Save', transactionHash})
            );
        } catch (err) {
            return Buffer.from(
                JSON.stringify({result: 400, message: err.message, transactionHash})
            );
        }
    }

    //Change modified of PO
    async update(stub, args, thisClass) {
        // args[0] =  order id, args[1] = completedMilestone
        if (args.length != 2) { //
            return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({result: 400, message: "Invalid arguments"}));
        }
        let timeStamp = stub
            .getTxTimestamp()
            .seconds
            .low;
        let orderAsByte = await stub.getState(args[0]);
        if (!orderAsByte || orderAsByte.length === 0) {
            return Buffer.from(
                JSON.stringify({result: 404, message: "order does not exist"})
            );
        }
        let transactionHash = stub.getTxID();
        let order = JSON.parse(orderAsByte);
        order.completedMilestone = args[1];
        order
            .updateLogs
            .push(
                {completedMilestone: order.completedMilestone, transactionHash: transactionHash, createdAt: timeStamp}
            )

        try {
            await stub.putState(args[0], Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(order)));
            return Buffer.from(
                JSON.stringify({result: 200, message: 'successfully update', transactionHash})
            );
        } catch (err) {
            return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({result: 400, message: err.message}));
        }
    }

    async queryOrder(stub, args, thisClass) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({result: 400, message: "Invalid arguments"}));
        }
        let queryString = args[0];
        let method = thisClass['getQueryResultForQueryString'];
        let queryResults = await method(stub, queryString, thisClass);
        return queryResults;
    }

    async getQueryResultForQueryString(stub, queryString, thisClass) {

        let resultsIterator = await stub.getQueryResult(queryString);
        let method = thisClass['getAllResults'];

        let results = await method(resultsIterator, false);

        return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(results));
    }

    async getAllResults(iterator) {
        let allResults = [];
        while (true) {
            let res = await iterator.next();

            if (res.value && res.value.value.toString()) {
                let jsonRes = {};

                jsonRes.Key = res.value.key;
                try {
                    jsonRes.Record = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));
                } catch (err) {
                    jsonRes.Record = res
                        .value
                        .value
                        .toString('utf8');

                }
                allResults.push(jsonRes);
            }
            if (res.done) {
                await iterator.close();
                console.info(allResults);
                return allResults;
            }
        }
    }

    async get(stub, args, thisClass) {
        if (args.length != 1) { //
            return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({result: 400, message: "Invalid arguments"}));
        }
        try {
            let orderAsByte = await stub.getState(args[0]);
            let order = JSON.parse(orderAsByte);
            console.info('GET <--> ', order);
            return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({result: 200, order: JSON.stringify(order)}));
        } catch (err) {
            return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({result: 404, message: 'Order Not Found'}));
        }
    }
};

shim.start(new Chaincode());
```

and it was working flawlessly with following snippet.

```
async function loadAdmin() {
    const adminKeystorePath = path.join(
        process.cwd(),
        "../",
        "network",
        "crypto-config",
        "peerOrganizations",
        "blockchain.kwiktrust.com",
        "users",
        "Admin@blockchain.kwiktrust.com",
        "msp",
        "keystore",
        "509c6e0476760a3eb9a6b37b7788f2178bb708e651e7f3f89a05d10eefc48522_sk");
    const keystore = fs.readFileSync(adminKeystorePath);
    const adminCertPath = path.join(
        process.cwd(),
        "../",
        "network",
        "crypto-config",
        "peerOrganizations",
        "blockchain.kwiktrust.com",
        "users",
        "Admin@blockchain.kwiktrust.com",
        "msp",
        "signcerts",
        "Admin@blockchain.kwiktrust.com-cert.pem"
    );
    const signCert = fs.readFileSync(adminCertPath)
    console.log('fabricHelper.js.loadAdmin().adminKeystorePath => ',adminKeystorePath);
    console.log('fabricHelper.js.loadAdmin().adminCertPath => ', adminCertPath);
    
    const state_store = await Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore(
        {path: store_path}
    )
    fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store)
    const crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite()
    const crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({path: store_path})
    crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store)
    fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite)
    let admin = await fabric_client.getUserContext("admin", true)
    if (!admin) {
        admin = await fabric_client.createUser({
            username: "admin",
            mspid: process.env.MSP,
            cryptoContent: {
                privateKeyPEM: keystore.toString(),
                signedCertPEM: signCert.toString()
            }
        })
        console.log('fabricHelper.js.loadAdmin.createUser =>', admin.getIdentity().toString())
        fabric_client.setUserContext(admin, true)
    }
    else{
        console.log('fabricHelper.js.loadAdmin.alreadyCreated =>', admin.getIdentity().toString())
    }
}
```

Above loads the user context in fabric client SDK and then the saveOrder to execute contract and submit transaction

```
function saveOrder(orderObj) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await loadAdmin()
        const tx_id = fabric_client.newTransactionID()
        
        let request = {
            chaincodeId: process.env.CHAIN_CODE_ID,
            fcn: "save",
            args: [JSON.stringify(orderObj)],
            chainId: process.env.CHANNEL,
            txId: tx_id
        }
        const results = await channel.sendTransactionProposal(request)
        const [proposalResponses,proposal] = results
        
        if (proposalResponses && proposalResponses[0].response && proposalResponses[0].response.status === 200) {
            const payload = JSON.parse(proposalResponses[0].response.payload.toString())
            console.log("channel.sendTransactionProposal:proposalResponses[0].response.status =>", proposalResponses[0].response.status)
            console.log("channel.sendTransactionProposal:proposalResponses[0].response.payload =>", payload.result)
            if (payload.result == 200) {
                request = {
                    proposalResponses,
                    proposal
                }
                const sendRequest = await channel.sendTransaction(request)
                console.log('sendRequest.Status =>', sendRequest);
                if (sendRequest && sendRequest.status === "SUCCESS") {
                    resolve(true)
                } else {
                    reject(false)
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unable to get payload success in porposal response")
                reject(false)
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Unable to get payload success in porposal response")
            reject(false)
        }
    })
}
```

Now I have changed shim to fabric-contract-api:-1.4.0 and exporting two contracts Project and Folder.

As i stated I want more then one contract files, but I have no idea how to execute the transaction the same way that I did for one contract, as channel.getContract is not any function. I tried another way that uses FileSystemWallet in fabric-sample 1.4 fabcar which required enrollAdmin and registerUser options but there i get authentication failure when I even try to enroll admin and probably because of my lack of knowledge on how to setup connections.json.

```
// Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'http','utils','hfc-key-store');
const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);
        
// Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
const userExists = await wallet.exists('user1');
if (!userExists) {
    console.log('An identity for the user "admin" does not exist in the wallet');
    console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
    return;
}
const gateway = new Gateway();
await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: false } });

// Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');

// Get the contract from the network.
const contract = network.getContract('Project');
```

This way i get to submit transaction on contract but when i run enrollAdmin.js before running registerUser.js script it gives me unable to enroll Authentication Failure.
Its been only four days since i started working on hyper-ledger so any help is appriciated..

Comment: I think `enrollAdmin.js` works with enrolling the CA bootstrap identity. Are you giving the right Fabric CA bootstrap identity credentials, i.e. `id.name` and `id.secret` corresponding to it?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to have a comment here, Is there a way for me to confirm that?

Comment: You might have setup Fabric CA using a bootstrap identity, that is using either `fabric-ca-server init` command or `fabric-ca-server start` command in the docker-compose file that you would be using to start the CA.

Comment: ok, so when looked at fabric-ca-server start command and used the id and secret from that. I get a different error which says 
"Failed to enroll admin user "admin": ReferenceError: ccp is not defined"

Comment: The connection profile object needs to be set correctly by referencing the correct path to the network's common connection profile.